# Combinatronics graph theory

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to prove the following: 
Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive integers and let $n > xyz$ be an integer. Prove that any sequence of $n$ (not necessarily distinct) real numbers contains an increasing subsequence of length $x + 1$, a decreasing subsequence of length $y + 1$ or a constant subsequence of length $z + 1$.

I can prove part of this using the Pigeonhole Principle, but I am unsure on how to complete the proof and the best way to write this up.

Comment: You should really change the title. I don’t know what would fit the most. But your question is not about graph theory.

Comment: Nor is there a field called "combinatronics".

Answer (score 1):

Label each number $x_n$ on the sequence with a triple $(a_n,b_n,c_n)$. $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ will encode the lengths of the longest increasing, decreasing and constant subsequences ending in $x_n$, respectively.

Note that every one of these three numbers must be a positive integer. Furthermore note that no two numbers $x_m$ and $x_n$ (with $m<n$ WLOG) can be associated to the same triple, since otherwise, depending on whether $x_m$ is less, is greater, or is equal to $x_n$, we would have $a_m<a_n$, $b_m<b_n$, or $c_m<c_n$. Therefore, we must have at least $xyz+1$ distinct labels, which necessarily means that for some $n$, either $a_n>x$, $b_n>y$, or $c_n>z$. This is precisely what we wished to prove.

By the way, your problem is essentially just an extended version of [Erdős–Szekeres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem?wprov=sfti1%20Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres). For more info, you might want to read up on that article.